# Getting ORA-01830 exception while running a proc in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a Update query

```
 Update configuration set comments='RUNNING'
         WHERE config_name = 'BName' and to_date(config_value) <= sysdate and comments is null;
```

config value is VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR) since this table is used to save multiple types of Configurations.

Current value in config_value is '03-MAY-23 01:41:31' and the above query works fine when run using a client. But when it is part of stored proc i am getting exception

```
   ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
2023-05-03T14:55:59.681+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ORA-06512: at "PKGtemp", line 2575
2023-05-03T14:55:59.681+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
2023-05-03T14:55:59.681+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ORA-06512: at "PKGTemp", line 2463
2023-05-03T14:55:59.681+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a string that constains a date/time. You know that format, but you don't tell the DBMS, but let it guess. One session guesses right, one guesses wrong, because this guessing depends on session settings. The solution is (of course) specifying the format for the conversion. As a month name is involved, you should also tell the DBMS the language used.

```
to_date(config_value, 'dd-MON-rr hh24:mi:ss', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN')
```

Here is the docs on `TO_DATE`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html

And here is the docs on the date formats: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-DFB23985-2943-4C6A-96DF-DF0F664CED96

Comment: at the time of your answer i used to_date(config_value,'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') <= to_date(sysdate,'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'). and as you said if we specify type it works

Comment: `SYSDATE` is already a datetime. If you invoke `TO_DATE` on it, the DBMS will have to convert the datetime to a string, for which it uses a default format, which again is session dependent. Then you assume that generated string is in format `'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'`., which you should not, because another session may have generated the date/time string in another format. There is no need to convert `SYSDATE` at all. You original query is correct in that aspect.